# Obtain a filename from a file handle?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, hook, dllimport

I have the ntdll.dll's NtCreateFile() function hooked to allow/deny the access of certain files. Unlike kernel32.dll's CreateFile() which easily gives you the full path to the file in question, ntdll.dll's NtCreateFile() function only gives you the handle to the file. I need to obtain the full path of the file from a file handle, to consequently allow/deny access. I've searched around and there doesn't seem to be a working C# solution.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789.aspx) solution is in C++, and documented from Microsoft. I've tried to port it over to C# with not much success. Here is my attempt at the C# equivalent of the C++ version of "obtaining a filename from a file handle":

```
    public string GetFileNameFromHandle(IntPtr FileHandle)
    {
        string fileName = String.Empty;
        IntPtr fileMap = IntPtr.Zero, fileSizeHi = IntPtr.Zero;
        UInt32 fileSizeLo = 0;

        fileSizeLo = GetFileSize(FileHandle, fileSizeHi);

        if (fileSizeLo == 0 && fileSizeHi == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // cannot map an 0 byte file
            return String.Empty;
        }

        fileMap = CreateFileMapping(FileHandle, IntPtr.Zero, FileMapProtection.PageReadonly, 0, 1, null);

        if (fileMap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr pMem = MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FileMapAccess.FileMapRead, 0, 0, 1);
            if (pMem != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                StringBuilder fn = new StringBuilder(250);
                GetMappedFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, pMem, fn, 250);
                if (fileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    UnmapViewOfFile(pMem);
                    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
                    return fn.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    UnmapViewOfFile(pMem);
                    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
                    return String.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

I have, of course, all the necessary DLLImports and user-defined types. When I use this function on handles, I get an empty string in return. It's also pretty hard to debug this, since this method is in a DLL that gets injected into a target process, not like something you can set a breakpoint at and enjoy Visual Studio's debugging system. I guess I could write a log file or some trace system, but I'm not that desperate yet. I just need a successful C# version of "get filename from file handle".

Any insight, code fixes, links?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question: why in the world are you doing this? *Hooking* a native API function call with a managed payload is bad enough (I certainly hope you've licensed Detours, because no other approach is supported), but with the purpose of applying a layer of security? Why not use the security built into the file system?

Comment: Looks like you need to look at writing minifilter driver which will allow you to make access decisions in a much more appropriate context.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540402(v=VS.85).aspx  Please, no hooking... Try opening a file on a network share or running it on Vista/7 x64.  The minifilter will work, your solution will blow up.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it myself. Here's the working code with the references and stuff.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetFileSize(IntPtr hFile, IntPtr lpFileSizeHigh);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(
    IntPtr hFile,
    IntPtr lpFileMappingAttributes,
    FileMapProtection flProtect,
    uint dwMaximumSizeHigh,
    uint dwMaximumSizeLow,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]string lpName);

[Flags]
public enum FileMapProtection : uint
{
    PageReadonly = 0x02,
    PageReadWrite = 0x04,
    PageWriteCopy = 0x08,
    PageExecuteRead = 0x20,
    PageExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
    SectionCommit = 0x8000000,
    SectionImage = 0x1000000,
    SectionNoCache = 0x10000000,
    SectionReserve = 0x4000000,
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(
    IntPtr hFileMappingObject,
    FileMapAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwFileOffsetHigh,
    uint dwFileOffsetLow,
    uint dwNumberOfBytesToMap);

[Flags]
public enum FileMapAccess : uint
{
    FileMapCopy = 0x0001,
    FileMapWrite = 0x0002,
    FileMapRead = 0x0004,
    FileMapAllAccess = 0x001f,
    fileMapExecute = 0x0020,
}

[DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetMappedFileName(IntPtr m_hProcess, IntPtr lpv, StringBuilder 
        lpFilename, uint nSize);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

public static string GetFileNameFromHandle(IntPtr FileHandle)
{
    string fileName = String.Empty;
    IntPtr fileMap = IntPtr.Zero, fileSizeHi = IntPtr.Zero;
    UInt32 fileSizeLo = 0;

    fileSizeLo = GetFileSize(FileHandle, fileSizeHi);

    if (fileSizeLo == 0)
    {
        // cannot map an 0 byte file
        return "Empty file.";
    }

    fileMap = CreateFileMapping(FileHandle, IntPtr.Zero, FileMapProtection.PageReadonly, 0, 1, null);

    if (fileMap != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr pMem = MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FileMapAccess.FileMapRead, 0, 0, 1);
        if (pMem != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            StringBuilder fn = new StringBuilder(250);
            GetMappedFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, pMem, fn, 250);
            if (fn.Length > 0)
            {
                UnmapViewOfFile(pMem);
                CloseHandle(FileHandle);
                return fn.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                UnmapViewOfFile(pMem);
                CloseHandle(FileHandle);
                return "Empty filename.";
            }
        }
    }

    return "Empty filemap handle.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789.aspx

"The following example obtains a file name from a handle to a file object using a file mapping object. It uses the CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile functions to create the mapping. Next, it uses the GetMappedFileName function to obtain the file name."

Code looks legit to me, hope that helps.

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure if you read my post, but that's what I said :P

Comment: I was only confirming that your code looks proper. And looking at the OP, the answer and the latest MSDN page the code still looks proper. What was the cause?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted here has been copied from the MSDN.
It has several disadvantages: It requires a real file bigger than 0 Bytes to work. It does not work for files of 0 Bytes nor does it work for directories. (and I'm not even talking about network drives)

I have posted a perfectly working code here:
[How to get name associated with open HANDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170/how-to-get-name-associated-with-open-handle/18792477#18792477)