# How can we convert a FILE* to a HANDLE?

Tags: c, winapi, file

Is there any where to convert a open `FILE*` returned from `fopen` to a `HANDLE` that is used in the Windows API functions? If so, how?

Comment: If you're willing to go the other way (which is more common), see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193579/how-make-file-from-handle-in-winapi which is creating a FILE * from a HANDLE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(HANDLE)`[`_get_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx)`(`[`_fileno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx)`( file ) )`

Good luck on 64-bit systems if you're using Visual C++ 2008 or earlier, though, because the return type is `long` on those. :(

Comment: @Neil: Thanks. :) Why? Portability?

Comment: @ Mehrdad  The FILE * stuff is an abstraction, If you don't want an abstraction, don't use it. But you can't have a bit of an abstraction.

Comment: @Neil: Well the issue is, you sometimes need the C-style abstraction for reading/writing files, but you sometimes need more info about the file, which you can only get with [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx). It's not an ideal solution but it's easier and somewhat better than migrating your entire code to `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` usage -- at least in that way, it'll be easier to port your code to other platforms later. (Not sure why you say *can't*, though.)

Comment: How does that snippet of code work though? Doesn't `_get_osfhandle` convert a HANDLE to a file descriptor? At least that's what's documented in the MSDN

Comment: @小太郎: No, it's the other way around; check MSDN again. (It's called `_get_osfhandle` because it "Gets the Operating System File **Handle**".)

Comment: Oh, I confused it with `_open_osfhandle` :P

Comment: @Mehrdad So basically, hacks are OK? Fair enough, and I've certainly done my share of them. But I would still question the hack, even if it was mine.

Comment: @Neil: Haha well, depends. If there's no alternative then you can't do anything about it, right? :)

Comment: One more question: Do I still need to close the handle returned by `_get_osfhandle` if I already `fclose`'d the original `FILE*`?

Comment: @小太郎: Nope, you don't, because by definition `_get_osfhandle` is the *internal* handle for the `FILE`, which isn't supposed to be managed by you.