# Application that get all opened files handles

Tags: windows, winapi, handle

I need an application like ProcessMonitor what cat get all opened files hadles in system. For example I have a hadle (from debugger) and I need to get a file name assigned to this handle. Is where any application what can help me, may be somebody know. Thanks.

Comment: Go you want to get all open handles, or do you want to get the file name associated with a file handle? Please can you decide, because there is an immense difference.

Comment: I need to get a file name associated with a file handle. This is the target for now.

Comment: If you would do a websearch you will find a gazillion questions on that topic already asked here. Someone with a spare dupehammer could close this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170/how-to-get-name-associated-with-open-handle

Comment: Oh! Thanks! GetFileInformationByHandleEx is all I need!